# Spring / Reactor : Retrieve and modify a Mono

Tags: spring, spring-boot, project-reactor

I have the following model :

```
class Person {
    List<Address> addresses;
}
```

I used the `ReactiveMongoRepository` to retrieve a Mono.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Person, String>{
}
```

But I can't find a way to add an Address to the person's addresses
 and return a Mono of the given Address.
Here is the signature of what I want to achieve :

```
Mono<Address> addAddress(Address address)
```

Here is the code I used to use without Reactor :

```
public Mono<Addresses> addAddress(Address address){
    Mono<Person> person = personRepository.findById(personId);
    // person.getAddresses().add(address) ?
    // personRepository.save(person) ?
    // return "address" as Mono
}
```

**Question:** How can I add an Address to a `Mono<Person>` and then return a Mono of that Address ?

Comment: if the `Address` is another persisted domain object then an `AddressRepository` needed as well and persist is before add to the `Person`

Comment: Well I chose to go for composition so there is no problem embedding the Address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do the trick:

```
public Mono<Addresses> addAddress(Address address){
        return personRepository.findById(personId)
                .doOnNext(p -> p.getAddresses().add(address))
                .flatMap(personRepository::save)
                .then(Mono.just(address));
}
```

`then()` waits for repository to save data, and after it completes, returns the address.

Another way is to extract (`map`) address from person returned by repository (it might be better solution, if address gets modified durning saving process)

```
public Mono<Addresses> addAddress(Address address){
        return personRepository.findById(personId)
                .doOnNext(p -> p.getAddresses().add(address))
                .flatMap(personRepository::save)
                .map(savedPerson -> savedPerson.getAddressess().findThisParticularJustSavedOne());
}
```

Comment: isn't doOnNext synchronous? If it throws exception, error signal insted of onNext signal is propagated. How could it be possibly done in asynchronous manner with 0 or 1 sequence?